# Android numberPicker inside listView stops scrolling when dataSet changes

Tags: android, listview, numberpicker

In my app I have a listView with a custom layout and a custom adapter. The layout contains a textView and a numberPicker.
I want the numberPicker to control a value of my data, so I want to add a setOnValueChangedListener to it. Without the listener, it works fine - when I scroll the numberPicker the numbers scroll, and when I scroll outside of it, it scrolls the list view, as demonstrated in the gif:

[image: numberPicker scrolling fine]

However, when I attach a setOnValueChangedListener to the numberPicker, things behave weirdly; When scrolling through the numberPicker, it will get stuck and cause the layout itself to scroll instead:

[image: numberPicker scrolling weirdly]

(In the gif I only scroll on the numberPickers, however it scrolls the listView and stops scrolling the numberPicker after the value has changed.)

Upon further investigation, it appears that notifyDataSetChanged() is what causes it to happen, and disabling it makes everything work fine.

What I think happens is that as I scroll through the numberPicker, the listener is firing for every value changed. So after just one increment, it fires and calls notifyDataSetChanged(), which somehow resets the views and causes the scrolling to stop and be transferred to the listView.

Here is all the relevant code:

The Application (The methods are not relevant and are used for when one of the button is pressed and creates a dialog):

```
package com.chdev.mypianopractice;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditPracticeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChoosePracticeStageDialogFragment.PracticeStageDialogListener {

    ArrayList<Practice.PracticeStage> practice;
    ListView listView;
    EditPracticeListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_practice);

        findViewById(R.id.practiceNameEditText).clearFocus();

        practice = new ArrayList<>();

        listView = findViewById(R.id.editPracticeListView);
        listView.setAdapter(new EditPracticeListViewAdapter(this, practice));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ((EditPracticeListViewAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setClickedPosition(position);
            }
        });

        adapter = (EditPracticeListViewAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    }

    // Creates a dialog in order to add a new stage.
    public void addStage(View view) {
        DialogFragment fragment = new ChoosePracticeStageDialogFragment();
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "chooseStage");
    }

    // Used by the dialog when adding new stages to the practice.
    @Override
    public void onDialogOK(Practice.PracticeType typeChosen) {
        String name = (typeChosen == null) ? "NULL" : getString(typeChosen.id);
        if (typeChosen != null) {
            practice.add(new Practice.PracticeStage(typeChosen, 30));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        System.out.println("The chosen activity: " + name);
    }
}
```

The custom adapter:

```
package com.chdev.mypianopractice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The adapter for the listView in EditPracticeActivity, using the custom layout.
 */

public class EditPracticeListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Practice.PracticeStage> {

    // Used for selecting items.
    private int lastClickedStage;

    public EditPracticeListViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Practice.PracticeStage> stages) {
        super(context, R.layout.practice_stage_row, stages);
        lastClickedStage = 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.practice_stage_row, parent, false);
        }
        Practice.PracticeStage stage = getItem(position);

        TextView text = rowView.findViewById(R.id.practiceStageNameTextView);
        text.setText(stage.type.id);

        NumberPicker picker = rowView.findViewById(R.id.practiceStageNumberPicker);
        picker.setMinValue(0);
        picker.setMaxValue(60*60);
        picker.setValue(stage.time);

        picker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                getItem(position).time = newVal;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        rowView.setBackgroundColor(position == lastClickedStage ? Color.LTGRAY : Color.WHITE);

        return rowView;
    }

    // Used for selecting items.
    public void setClickedPosition(int position) {
        lastClickedStage = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The layout of the activity:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_practice_title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/practiceNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/new_practice_default_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/editPracticeListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/practiceNameEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:onClick="addStage"
        android:text="@string/add_practice_stage_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="@string/remove_practice_stage_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="@string/save_practice_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="@string/quit_practice_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The custom layout used in the listView:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/practiceStageNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/practiceStageNumberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm sorry this is a bit lengthy. I'd really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!